# Create space-time cube plot in R

Tags: r, leaflet, plotly

[image: Example spacetime cube]

I would like to create an interactive plot like the fixed version shown here. my data is simple a list of event observations, each with a Date, lat, and long. Can I do this using plotly or leaflet? Having trouble finding any examples where the map is visible..

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

tibble(  
  lat = runif(1000, 25, 50),
  long = runif(1000, -128, -62),
  date = sample(seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), 1), 1000, replace = T) 
) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~long, y = ~lat, z = ~date)
```

Comment: Request for demonstrations should be accompanied by code that has been used and by links to data objects that might be needed.

Comment: here is example data and I would like to add the map image as above:


tibble(  
  lat = runif(1000, 25, 50),
  long = runif(1000, -128, -62),
  date = sample(seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), 1), 1000, replace = T) 
) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~long, y = ~lat, z = ~date)

Comment: I don’t see any image or link to a data object that could serve as a map.

Comment: correct - that's because I'm asking how

Comment: Since you don't want to play by the SO guidelines for question construction, let me refer you to an outside source: buy Sarkars "Lattice" book and go to chapter 6 "3D Visualisation".

Comment: I don't know what you mean about not wanting to play by the guidelines. I am asking how to add a map layer at the bottom/top of the graph i.e. at the min(date)/max(date) given the sample data above I provided. I don't have a map object to start with.

Comment: Hey, here's a cool resource: https://movebankworkshopraleighnc.netlify.app/testtimecube